# RecyclerView, different divider dependently on type of row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a ListView with different types of rows. I would like to disable divider for the first row and have another style of a divider for the second one.

What's the best practice to do that?

I'm adding dividers currently by:

```
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in the following way.

**Note:** In my solution, the divider is part of the Item view, you can set a background instead or draw a line, or add a bottom margin and let the space show the background hence creating a divider etc. I recommend looking at the [ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) api. I'm just showing you how to determine in ItemDecoration what you want to do.

First, in your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    if (mData.get(postion) instanceof ObjectA)
        holder.itemView.setTag(R.id.noSpaceAfter, Boolean.TRUE);
    else
        holder.itemView.setTag(R.id.noSpaceAfter, Boolean.FALSE);
    ...
}
```

Then in your `RecyclerView`, declare an `ItemDecoration`

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration());
```

Finally, define your `MyDividerItemDecorator`

```
public class MyDividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    public MyDividerItemDecoration () {
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        Boolean noSpace = (Boolean) view.getTag(R.id.noSpaceAfter);
        View v = view.findViewById(R.id.view_sep);
        if (v != null) {
            if (noSpace == null || !noSpace) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this in mind, you can just copy the source for [DividerItemDecoration](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.java) and then in it's `drawVertical` method, when you fetch the views in the loop, check to see if `R.id.noSpaceAfter` is true or false and skip drawing accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

try to add  in your row xml file at bottom of layout and define required layout_height and set layout_width="match_parent"  and hide view at particular index that you want

eg-

```
`<View   
   android:id="@+id/view_divider"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="@dimen/one"   
    android:background="@color/grey_divider_color"/>`
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as quick solution, but I prefer more robust one.

Answer (score 1):

@Ali I like your solution. However, your code requires divider in a layout. I solved it by hiding regular divider. Thank you for the hint anyway. Here is my class:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider};

private Drawable divider;

/**
 * Default divider will be used
 */
public DividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
    final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    divider = styledAttributes.getDrawable(0);
    styledAttributes.recycle();
}

/**
 * Custom divider will be used
 */
public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int resId) {
    divider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View row = parent.getChildAt(i);
        Boolean noDivider = (Boolean) row.getTag(R.id.noSpaceAfter);

        if (noDivider == null || !noDivider) {
            drawDivider(canvas, row, left, right);
        }
    }
}

private void drawDivider(Canvas canvas, View row, int left, int right) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) row.getLayoutParams();

    int top = row.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
    int bottom = top + divider.getIntrinsicHeight();

    divider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    divider.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

Comment: As I mentioned, I can show you how to determine in ItemDecoration what you need to do, I even mentioned the exact approach you took at the bottom. Please accept the answer as the correct answer if it helped you.